# What is a Dirac semimetal?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, topological-insulators

What is the precise definition of a [Dirac semimetal](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Dirac+semimetal)?  Is it sufficient for two bands to touch at a single k point with a linear crossing, or are more conditions required for a material to be called a Dirac semimetal?

Comment: Usually the result of a 50-50 alloy between a Heisenberg hard rock and some Schrödinger blues.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Is that the Schrödinger Dead Cat Blues? I've been looking for a copy ...

Answer (score 1):

Some looking around yields two papers for you to start with:

[S.M. Young et al., Dirac Semimetal in Three Dimensions](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.140405) is more of a theory paper, where they show that certain space groups allow for 3D Dirac points with the required degeneracies. They show/derive the appropriate conditions, which is probably the best bet for a 'precise definition'.

The second is [Sergey Borisenko et al., Experimental Realization of a Three-Dimensional Dirac Semimetal](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.027603) which experimentally investigates, using angle-resolved photoemission spectroscopy, the band structure of Cd$_{3}$As$_{2}$ to show it is (or acts) like a three dimensional Dirac semimetal.

From those you should be able to work backwards for the evolution of the term.